# Bower git package with a commit id

Tags: javascript, node.js, bower

Is it possible to include a github repo from a specific id?

For example I need `angular.js` repo with `e12e584ca8db306dce8e0f4d3a212d77fbae966c` id.

Is this possible?

```
 "dependencies": 
      "angular-my-repo":"https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/e12e584ca8db306dce8e0f4d3a212d77fbae966c",
      "moment": "~2.1.0"
 },
```

or what is the correct syntax?

Comment: That URL seems to be going to the GitHub page for the commit, and not the code. Bower does support local endpoints, so you could clone the repo, checkout the commit you want, and point Bower to that.

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake. The correct url is https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/e12e584ca8db306dce8e0f4d3a212d77fbae966c

Comment: for bower registered repos, just put the commit id instead of version. `"angular":"e12e584ca8db306dce8e0f4d3a212d77fbae966c"`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
bower install --save git://github.com/angular/angular.js#e12e584ca8db306dce8e0f4d3a212d77fbae966c
```

or

```
bower install --save https://github.com/angular/angular.js.git#e12e584ca8db306dce8e0f4d3a212d77fbae966c
```

see this thread

https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/856

Comment: Thanks! This saved me the day!

Comment: That didn't work but for me creating a new tag then using it - for example on github git://github.com/angular/angular.js#1.4.3 did work

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Cemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/360594/cemo)'s answer,
It is possible to install bower package from a commit using the char '#'

i.e

```
bower install --save package_name#commit_sha
```

e.g

```
bower install --save angular.js#e12e584ca8db306dce8e0f4d3a212d77fbae966c
```

This will add to your bower.json the depndency

```
"angular.js":"e12e584ca8db306dce8e0f4d3a212d77fbae966c"
```

Hope this helps!